# What is the number after the second colon on a Google Apps Script error?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script linked to a Sheet that takes Form responses. I'm getting this error:
[image: Error screenshot]
I've figured out that 104 is the line number where the error occurs. What does 14 represent? Both numbers are the same every time the error occurs. For context's sake, here's some of the code:

```js
if (Renaming) {
    Debug("Renaming Began")
    var Section = Values[4]
    var Name = Values[5].replace(/\//g, "-").concat(" ", Values[3], "-", Values[2].substring(0, 1)) // Date, space, last name, hyphen, first initial
    Debug("Renaming Files...")
    DriveApp.getFileById(Documents[0]).setName(Section.concat(" Session Plan ", Name)) // Session plan naming (this is line 104)
    Debug("Session Plan Renamed")
    DriveApp.getFileById(Documents[1]).setName(Section.concat(" Sign-in ", Name))
    Debug("Sign-in Sheet Renamed")
    if (Documents.length > 2) {
      Debug("Worksheets Detected")
      Debug(Documents.length)
      for (i = 2; Documents.length; i++) {
        if (i > 13) {break}
        Debug(("Began ").concat(i))
        if (!Documents[i]) {continue}
        Debug(("Exists ").concat(i))
        DriveApp.getFileById(Documents[i]).setName(Section.concat(" Worksheet #", i - 1, " ", Name))
        Debug(("Renamed ").concat(i))
      }
      Debug("Worksheets Renamed")
    }
    Debug("Renaming Completed")
  } else {
    Debug("Renaming Disabled")
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

From this expression: `104:14`:

`104`: represents the row where the error occured.

`14`: represents the column where the error occured.

Column is defined as the position of each character in the document on the horizontal axis. Each symbol/space/letter/number occupies **one** column of space.

**Example:**

[image]

- the error here is in the `2`nd row and there are `2` spaces (columns) before the word `error`.
- But the error **starts** at the letter `e` of the word `error`. So you have `2` spaces (columns) before `error` plus a letter which is the position where the error started. Two spaces and one letter equals to `3` columns. Therefore, you have an error that is located in the `3rd` column.

  [image]

In your case, the error is located at the row `104` and there are `13` symbols/spaces/letters or numbers before the command that introduces the error. Everything before column `14` is correct. The error starts at column `14`.